# MySQL Multiple select

Tags: mysql, polymorphic-associations

I have an indextable which hold a content_id and type colomn.
(eg. content_id=1, type=audio.  content_id=1, type=video) Would it be possible to get the right data based upon content_id from the right tables (tables: contentvideo, contentaudio)?

Comment: can you clarify exactly what tables you have and what fields they have?

Comment: I added the `polymorphic-associations` tag, because that's what you're doing.  Follow the tag to see other questions related to this database design.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to retrieve the content via a single select statement? If the layout of your content tables is exactly the same you can use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html):

```
SELECT ca.* FROM contentaudio ca, indextable it
 WHERE ca.content_id = it.content_id
   AND it.content_type = 'audio'
UNION
SELECT cv.* FROM contentvideo cv, indextable it
 WHERE cv.content_id = it.content_id
   AND it.content_type = 'video'
ORDER BY content_id /* or whatever */
```

Note that if `content_id` is not unique across all of your `content` tables, you may get multiple records (of different types) for the same `content_id`. Also note that if you're selecting a particular record based on some `indextable` key, you'll need to add it to each part of the union.

If your `content` tables have **different** layouts, you can use an [OUTER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) instead and retrieve your various content types as part of one record (missing ones will be returned as NULLs):

```
SELECT * FROM indextable it
  LEFT OUTER JOIN contentaudio ca ON it.content_id = ca.content_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN contentvideo cv ON it.content_id = cv.content_id
 WHERE it.some_key = ?
```

Note that `content_type` is not involved in this case at all (nor do you really need it for UNION select either).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CASE, or IF?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/6.0/en/case-statement.html

Comment: I've read up in the MysSQL on the link you gave. The concept is clear, the examples are poor, but I did some searching and I found just what i needed based on your CASE gesture. Thanks!

For other people who might stumble upon the same thing. Here's the link that I needed (a SELECT based on a CASE switch)
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,245909,245990#msg-245990